# Is there a XQuery 3.0 implementation for .NET?

Tags: .net, xquery

I am looking for an XQuery 3.0 implementation for .NET. Do any exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XmlPrime](https://www.xmlprime.com/) 3.0 does indeed support XQuery 3.0 and XPath 3.0.

Answer (score 3):

There is [XMLPrime](http://www.xmlprime.com/xmlprime/index.htm) (formerly XQSharp) which is a native .NET XQuery library, *but only supports XQuery 1.0*.

[Saxon](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/dotnetdoc/index.html) provides XQuery/XSLT processing in both Java and .NET and can be embedded as library. Lots of other XML Databases (that *might* provide better or worse performance, depending on document, document size and use cases) have interfaces, have a look at [BaseX](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex-api/tree/master/src/main/c%23), [Marklogic](http://www.marklogic.com/products-and-services/marklogic-6/) and [probably more](http://www.w3.org/XML/Query/#implementations). They all have XQuery 3.0 support, but you will have to run them as a standalone which you can access using some .NET-native interface.

All of them have special (dis-)advantages, so choosing one depends heavily on your needs.

Comment: It seems XMLPrime does have partial support for some XQuery 3.0 features, such as [functions](http://www.xmlprime.com/xmlprime/doc/2.5/P_XmlPrime_XdmModule_XQuery30Functions.htm), operators and serialization. See *Implemented standards* on [this page](http://www.xmlprime.com/xmlprime/doc/2.5/overview.htm).

Comment: I have not used it, but one of our users (I'm with BaseX) published http://nxdb.codeplex.com/ which is basically a cross-compiled version of Java based BaseX to .NET

Comment: Saxon(.Net) isn't an XML Database, but an XSLT/XQuery processor, and can be used as .Net library directly.

Comment: Thank you for telling: You're right, that post was not fully correct. I did an edit.

Answer (score 2):

XmlPrime should support XQuery 3.0 by the time the standard reaches Candidate Recommendation.  At the time of writing it still in draft.